# How many local ports should be opened when using Java to make URL server calls?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Using a simple Server process.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;

public class EmbeddedJettyExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server(8888);

        ServletHandler servletHandler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(servletHandler);

        servletHandler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/");

        server.start();
        server.join();

    }

    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
               }
        }
 }
```

The following client code is used to call the above server.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class URLCalls 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int numOfIterations = 1;
    
    if (args.length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            numOfIterations = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            numOfIterations = 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= numOfIterations; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println("Processing iteration : " + i);
        makeServerCall();
    } 

    System.out.println("Exiting");
}

private static void makeServerCall() 
{
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection con;
    int responseCode = 0;

    try 
    {
            url = new URL("http://myServer:8888/EmbeddedJettyExample");
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("     Connect Response Code :: " + responseCode);
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
            { 
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                ((HttpURLConnection)con).disconnect();
                url = null;
                con = null;

                System.out.println("     " + response.toString());
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("     GET request failed");
            }
        }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
}
```

The above accepts 1 argument which is the number of times to execute the server call.

```
> java URLCalls 250
```

While the client code is executing, netstat is executed on the client.

```
 > nestat > myfile.txt
```

Editing the myfile.txt, I expect to see a large number of ports allocated and referencing the application and server but here is only 1 entry. I even run the above netstat command during the start, middle and near the end and there is always just 1 port and its the same client port reference. To be sure there any other entries, 8888 is search and there is only 1 entry.

```
 Proto  Local Address              Foreign Address        State
   TCP    myLocalMachine:52624      myServer:8888         ESTABLISHED
```

The client code does ensure the objects are closed and nulled.

**Questions**

1 - Why is the same client port being used?

2 - Why is there not a new client port being allocated for each call?

3 - Is there a command or code change required to ensure a new client port is accessed each time?

Comment: You client is a single thread application and the request are done sequentially. Perfect for re-using the same port / connection.

Comment: At what level is the decision to utilize the same port being done? Is that at the OS level or Java level?

Comment: Unable to edit, so adding new comment......Once I placed the call into a thread and spawned a thread each call I now see individual connections.  Thanks, but still curious at what level (Java or OS) the choice to reuse the port is made.

Comment: I am not aware that you can select a port for outgoing connections, only for ServerSockets.

Comment: I think in this case the `HttpUrlConnection` itself will keep the connection alive (i.e. it's not even that the same port number is used, it's in fact the same TCP connection executing multiple HTTP requests via pipelining).